# The area enclosed by curve $r^2=9\cos 5\theta$

Tags: integration, area

Find the area enclosed ny the curve $r^2=9\cos 5\theta$.

I have drawn its graph and it is the rose which has 5 petals. In order to find the total area it's sufficient to find the area of one petal.

So the total area will be $$5\int \limits_{-\pi/10}^{\pi/10}\dfrac{r^2}{2}d\theta=\dfrac{45}{2}\int \limits_{-\pi/10}^{\pi/10}\cos 5\theta\ d\theta=9$$

I think that my answer is definitely correct. However the answer on the book is 18. But this answer would be reasonable if this curve had 10 petals but it is wrong.

Can anyone explain who have made a mistake?

Comment: 5 petal rose is for one value. Note that the equation has $r^2$ so there are two cases $r = \pm 3 \sqrt{cos(5\theta)}$ I hope this helps

Comment: Let's take $\theta=2\pi/10$ then $5\theta=\pi$ and $r^2=-1$. It seems meaningless. Am I wrong?

Comment: $9$ is the right answer

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I also think that 9 is the right answer. THanks

Comment: Oh hmm. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, Let me ask you one question: But what's wrong with SMath's suggestion? Namely with $r=\pm 3\sqrt{\cos 5\theta}$?

Comment: after squaring  and plug into your formula it is the same

Comment: Ahh yes. But polar curve $r=\pm 3\sqrt{\cos 5\theta}$ has 10 petals right? And then answer will be indeed 18